# Is it safe to inject Authentication State Provider in MainLayout since it is a shared or public folder?

Tags: layout, blazor, blazor-server-side, basic-authentication

I have two public layout which is LoginLayout and MainLayout. My login layout is for my login page and the user info was stored in my claimsprincipal and when the user successfully logged, I displayed my user id in my main layout.

I successfully displayed it, is it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's totally safe to do so. As long as `MainLayout` is just a Razor component (.razor file), it's on the same 'level' as any other page or component.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want to up vote your answer but I was not allowed due to my reputation score. Hehe.

Comment: @CheAcebz you can mark it as the correct answer with the checkmark below the vote buttons

Comment: alright, done. Thank you, I am new member so I don't know how this things works.